# Cloud Functions, File remoteconfig.template.json does not exist

Tags: google-cloud-functions

when I set up Cloud Functions folders through firebase init, everything works fine

but when I enter "firebase deploy" it keeps showing

```
Error: File remoteconfig.template.json does not exist
```

I guess I also created that file when setting up.

I googled but nothing found. how to solve this?

Comment: if you are using remoteconfig service from firebase then you need to have remote config json file https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/templates

Comment: @Methkal Khalawi do I have to make this manually? when initation, the CLI asks me "are you gonna make the remote config file" as  
remoteconfig.template.json so I entered 'Y'

Comment: if you are not using remote config then just remove it from firebase.json file

Comment: @MethkalKhalawi thanks my friend can you answer this question also please?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64583257/cloud-functions-deleting-firestore-subcollections-is-admintoken-necessary

Comment: I have added any answer for your question. please accept for more visibility for the community. I will check your other question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your question I understand that you are not using remote config product from firebase. just remove its definition from firebase.json and everything will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It may happen if you init Firebase project in parent folder and `remoteconfig.template.json` file is created there instead of inside `functions` folder. Check if the file exist outside `functions` folder or inside parent folder. If yes, move it inside `functions` folder and boom 'firebase deploy' will work without showing error now.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me when I was running firebase deploy from inside the "functions" folder by accident (the file remoteconfig.template.json is in my root dir).
I moved to the parent directory (my project root) and everything worked.